# Google Cloud master Failure

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Master instance of google cloud sql keeps failing randomly and when it goes to fail-over, I got "The MySQL server is running with the --read-only". I changed the fail-over(replica) mysql instance to read-only : false. This removed the read only error but now the master and replica are not in sync.

Also, it keeps randomly pointing to the replica, suggesting that the master is down.

How do I get the master and replica in sync again?
Why does the master keep failing?

Thank you team!

Comment: They seem to be experiencing somewhat widespread issues with Cloud SQL. I've submitted a ticket with them. Someone else reported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443305/google-cloud-sql-is-now-read-only

Comment: Definitely not just you. Ours is doing the same thing -- randomly sending some connections to our failover replica even though our master is still up.