# Google Cloud SQL is now Read Only

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

We have an issue With Google Cloud SQL (Second Generation).

Most inserts are failing with the following error:

> The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement.

We have made no changes. This suddenly started happening. Tried restarting the Google Cloud SQL instance but it had no effect.

Any suggestions on how we might fix quickly?

Comment: Not all inserts are failing. Failure rate appears to be linked to connecting server location with Europe and Asia very badly affect.

Comment: We've started having this issue as well. Working on submitting a high priority ticket to them now.

Comment: It appears that it's randomly sending traffic to our failover replica, which is read only.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am seeing also. Interestingly this is not happening to a server I have in us-central1-b - this server is working fine.

Comment: Have you heard anything back from Google? I emailed cloud-sql@google.com over 2 hours ago and had nothing back. I'm considering deleting the failover replica to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Not really. Just that they're "working very hard to ensure that this issue is resolved quickly for you".  The guy at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444533/1290-error-on-google-cloud-sql apparently had success just deleting the failover.

We're trying manually switching to the failover as documented at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ha#test, but do NOT recommend that as it's been trying for over 25 minutes and we can't cancel it and it's just turned the intermittent issue into a constant one.

Comment: I deleted the failover replica and that got us up and running again. We had to do this in desperation - we had already lost over 3 hours of data - over 50,000 records. Really angry about this, we moved to a managed SQL service to avoid issues like this. Deleting a failover replica is a pretty bad solution to a problem!

Comment: Facing same problem for last two days :(

Answer (score 2):

Google have fixed the problem. Their response was:

We had a problematic configuration that was directing traffic to both master and replica. The changes should have been reverted and you shouldn't see this issue anymore.

Comment: Facing same problem for last two days :(

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the failover replica and after a few seconds it works well again. It seems that it was a problem with the replica readonly message.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this seems to happen from time to time on Google CloudSQL. We've configured an alarm that listens to this error in our logs and after restarting the application it usually starts working again.