# 1290 Error on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I just started getting this Error today while using MySQL workbench, and noticed it showing up in my application as far back as saturday.  Anyone else getting it?
Have any idea what might be causing it?

**ERROR**
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

**Running just a simple insert generates the error.  Eg..**
INSERT INTO `Job1111`.`SubsWeld` 
(`fk_SubmissionId`, `WeldSpool1`, `WeldSpool2`, `WeldDrawingNumber`, `WeldLineNumber`, `WeldSheetNumber`, `WeldTimeInForm`, `WeldLineSpec`, `WeldNumber`, `WeldStencil`, `WeldSize`, `WeldThickness`, `WeldType`, `WeldPosition`, `WeldMaterial`, `WeldProcedure`, `WeldComplete`, `WeldShared`, `WeldPercentCompleted`, `WeldRework`, `ActivityType`, `Rev`) 
VALUES ('66', '5990-363-A', '5990-363-B', 'V-0020-3', '12-V-0020', '3', '0', 'A', '1059', '1059', '24.00', 'Sch. 40', 'BW', '5G', 'CS', '1013 Rev2', '1', '0', '100', '0', '22', '0');

Comment: We're experiencing the same or a similar issue. It appears to be randomly connecting to our failover instead of our master. We have a ticket in with Google now but haven't heard anything yet except that they're looking into it.

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not alone... I'm considering shutting down my Failover for the time being.  Have you tried that as a temp fix?

Comment: We're also considering it, but haven't tried it yet simply because something feels wrong about deleting our real time backup while having issues. I'll let you know if it helps anything if we do end up trying it though.

Comment: FYI, My operation is in alpha testing currently, so I had the flexibility to try it.   Deleting the replica cleared up my issue instantly.   The only downfall I see currently is Now I won't have a solid way to be able to tell when the issue is resolved, short of trying it out time to time.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! We tried manually switching over to the failover as documented here (cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ha#test) but that has been running for over an hour now and still hasn't switched and has just frozen up our instances so we can't do anything with them now.

We're in the process of setting up everything on another DB server to get back up and running. I'll let you know what Google responds with though once it's back up.

Comment: Any word on how this issue is coming along for you RLHawk?

Comment: It's a huge disaster for us. Turns out the failover wasn't and hadn't been in sync with the master since sometime yesterday morning, before the other issues showed up. Stackdriver still showed it as 0 ms behind the master, but when switching to the failover finally finished after 3 hours or so, it seems data from the whole day was lost completely. We've got all of our top tier clients on Compute Engine and Cloud SQL using our software to run their businesses.

Comment: Google finally responded that they were pushing out a fix and that we didn't need to do anything. I see all our 2nd generation instances had an update pushed to them, presumably with the fix.  "As Cloud SQL 2nd Generation is in Beta, issues are to be expected and I want to thank you for opening this case with us."

I guess we just didn't take the beta tag seriously enough. In this environment, I took it more as "Things are subject to change" than "This may or may not work."

Comment: I just took a look through my operations on my google sql server... I have not noticed any updates since Jul 12.  So I'm curious if mine is fixed.   Did the pushed update that you noticed fix your issue?

Comment: Sorry -- we haven't actually re-enabled it to see if it is working simply because we can't afford it to not work at the moment. Haven't decided yet what we're going to do but I'll let you know if/when we do! Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Facing same problem for last two days :(

Comment: UPDATE: I have yet to revisit this issue to see if it is still lurking in the shadows...