# Google Cloud SQL second generation | The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We have an issue With Google Cloud SQL (Second Generation).

### *Setup* :

`Master | Failover | Read replica`

At application side we're getting the below error sporadically, have no idea what is causing this :

`The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement`

Any idea what is causing, this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud SQL is now Read Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443305/google-cloud-sql-is-now-read-only)

Comment: @Mohamed Abada, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."